# pystache - return all templates in a string

Tags: python, pystache

In pystache (or most templating libraries), you can do a substitution such as this:

```
>>> print pystache.render('{{person}} in {{place}}', {'person': 'Mom', 'place': 'Spain'})
Mom in Spain
```

Is it possible to do the 'opposite'? i.e. return a dictionary (or more correctly, a set) with all the templates in a string?

```
>>> templates = pystache.get_templates('{{person}} in {{place}}')
>>> print templates
{'person', 'place'}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for `pystache` functionality, but it may not have a way to do this.  Fortunately, you can do this with a simplex regex:

```
import re
string = "{{person}} in {{place}}"
matches = re.findall("({{.+?}})", string)
print matches
```

This outputs: `['{{person}}', '{{place}}']`

Comment: Thanks. I ended up doing something similar. Was hoping to do it directly in pystache. Might submit it as an issue/request.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you can parse it out like this:

```
parsed = pystache.parse("{{person}} in {{place}}")
print(parsed)
```

which gives the reuslt:

```
[_EscapeNode(key='person'), ' in ', _EscapeNode(key='place')]
```

(found in pystache docs [here](https://github.com/defunkt/pystache))